# Redirection the target field should ensured its a valid request

Tags: javascript, redirect, logout

I have a logout button and when i click logout it is redirected to other site (http://rtfg.internal.com/LandingPage). The target makes sure the page gets redirected.
https://abc.internal.com/logout.html?target=http://rtfg.internal.com/LandingPage . I was thinking of the case where an attacker puts some link in the target and does some malicious attack . Is there a way to ensure we have a valid redirect and nothing unwanted is added to target field ?

Comment: Um… no. Just don't do anything stupid with URL data, like going to the redirect page with admin access or something.

Comment: I mostly agree with @bjb568 ... but there may be something you could do. Create an array of valid redirect pages in your code, and pass the array index as the URL parameter. Then your code would (1) validate whether the array index is valid, (2) get the predetermined URL from the array, and finally (3) redirect to it.

Comment: The only problem is the url target field can be anything.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this ? URL referrer is not going to validate the url :(

Comment: Before the redirection i am checking if the url is to redirect only if it is from particular domain else do not redirect . Does this appproach solve my purpose ?